# How do I optimise joining multiple Firebase Firestore collection document values together in Angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, primeng

I am looking for a more optimal way to implement the following method getting all my documents from my permits collection, than mapping company and process area data into my permit data used in a PrimeNG table.

Performance > Firebase document reads usage.

Here is my `getAllPermits$()` method so far:

```
getAllPermits$() {
    return combineLatest([
      collectionData(this.permitCollection) as Observable<any[]>, //will query this later to only show active permits
      collectionData(this.companyCollection, {idField: 'uid'}) as Observable<Company[]>,
      collectionData(this.processAreasCollection, {idField: 'uid'}) as Observable<ProcessArea[]>,
    ]).pipe(
      map(([permits, companies, processAreas]) => {
        return permits.map(permit => {
          if (permit.companyUid) {
            const company = companies.find(c => c.uid === permit.companyUid);
            if (company) {
              permit = {...permit, companyName: company?.name ?? 'Error'};
            } else {
              permit = {...permit, companyName: 'Not Found'};
            }
          } else {
            permit = {...permit, companyName: 'No Company'};
          }

          if (permit.processArea) {
            const processArea = processAreas.find(pa => pa.assetNumber === permit.processArea);
            if (processArea) {
              permit = {...permit, processAreaName: processArea?.description ?? 'Error'};
            } else {
              permit = {...permit, processAreaName: 'Not Found'};
            }
          } else {
            permit = {...permit, processAreaName: 'No Process Area'};
          }
          return permit;
        });
      })
    );
  }
```

Is querying single documents in the `companyCollection` and `processAreasCollection` more efficient, as opposed to mapping as shown above?

**Context:**
I would normally have 200 - 500 active permits (this isn't in the code yet, but this is easy implement later).

- `companyCollection` = 300+ companies where we might use 100-150 companies in the currently active permits.
- `processAreas` = 160+ areas - again, we might use 50-70 areas in the actively shown permits.

I am using a big portion of the company and process area collection data, hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the best performance, move away from the relational model that you currently have, and embrace the NoSQL nature of Firestore by duplicating data.

For example, if you duplicate the data that you need from `processAreasCollection` and `companyCollection` into each document in `permitCollection`, you only need to load the documents from the latter. This may seem very unnatural at first, but it's actually key to getting great performance out of a NoSQL database like Firestore.

If this is new to you, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching the [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) video series.

Comment: Sigh... I think you are right. Now is probably a best time to refactor my code a little bit. I am still not entirely sure how to handle changing information. For example: Process Area names update more than we'd like... In this case would I create a cloud function (onUpdate) when it changes to go change it on every permit document?

Comment: Don't underestimate the power of something like Cloud Functions to handle fan-out of data updates. They're quite good at it. That said, if the values update too frequently, you can also keep loading those values from single points of definition, i.e. their current source documents, or a set of documents just contain the values you need. I do prefer Realtime Database for that myself, as its data model doesn't have a 1MB-per-document size limit (since it doesn't have anything like a document, and is just one big JSON tree).

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't change that frequently to worry about real time database (5-10 areas might change a month). Thanks Frank.

Answer (score 1):

faster searches could be done by using `Map`, then instead of `.find` which takes `O(n)` it would take you only `O(1)` operations for search

```
const companiesMap = new Map(companies.map(c => [c.uid, c]));
const areasMap = new Map(processAreas.map(p => [p.assetNumber, p]));
return permits.map(permit => {
  const companyName = permit.companyUid ? companiesMap.get(permit.companyUid)?.name ||  'Not Found' : 'No Company';
  const processAreaName = ... areasMap.get(permit.processArea) ... ;
  return {
    ...permit,
    companyName,
    processAreaName,

  }
})
```

this way there shouldn't be a problem with long remapping. But you'll probably get some freezes during rendering large lists of data.

Comment: Works great, this is already an improvement over my code.